# Why is the number in league link changed?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, russian-stackoverflow

Today I noticed that the number of community (?) is changed in the reputation league address. E.g. it was [355 before and now is 609](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6582/revisions) for Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: diff]

The old link now refers to a 404 page. Why has the number been changed?