# Selected position of combobox on reputation league page is broken

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

Changing the selected item in the dropdown combobox on the [reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/) works wrong for many sites:

> [image: rep league]

It seems that numbers of sites (communities) are changed [somehow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314438/339911) and not synced on the page.

Comment: @Arulkumar thanx, upvoted!

Comment: still remains..